# How do I call a function from one class in another?

Tags: python, class, methods

I am having a hard time understanding how to call a function or method from one class in to another. In other words, how do I call the `mailbox` function from the class `House` in the class `Player`, so that when I type in `mailbox` the string `"There is an old mailbox"` is printed out?

```
class House(object):

    def __init__(self, mailbox, door, vindov):
        self.house = House()
        self.mailbox = mailbox
        self.door = door
        self.vindov = vindov

    def door(self):
        print "There is nothjing special about this door"

    def vindov(self):
        print "The vindov seems to be half open"

    def mailbox(self):
        print "there is an old mailbox"


class Player(House):

    while True:
        action = raw_input("> ")
        if action == "mailbox":
```

Comment: Why do you need to house your logic in player? What problem are you trying to solve here, and in case you want to call the `mailbox` method from `House`, all you need to do is `super().mailbox` and that will resolve to `House`'s `mailbox` method.

Comment: thank you for your help, i am doing the logic in player be cos i have no idea on how to make an engine for the game, i can do this perfectly just with functions, but i want to do it also with classes

Comment: and i am trying this: since this is a text based game, when ever the user types in mailbox, i want that the program prints out the string "There is an old mailbox"

Answer (score 0):

Since `Player` inherits from `House`, you can simply invoke the `mailbox` method from `House` inside player by `self.mailbox()`. You can also call the super-class's method by `super().<method name in super class>`.

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self, t):
...         self.t = t
...
...     def mailbox(self):
...         print("This is an old mailbox")
>>> class B(A):
...     def new_mailbox(self):
...         self.mailbox()
...
...
...
>>> b = B("hello")
>>> b.new_mailbox()
This is an old mailbox
```

Comment: do i have to create afunction in the player class in order to call the mailbox function in class House? can i not just call the function without a new function? what if i dont use inheritance?

Comment: No you can't you have to have some way of referring to the super class, and thats with `self`. Also, this is not how you make a game engine, and if you want to make an engine with functions there's no problem. Don't use classes where you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

As Games Brainiac has pointed out, you can invoke the method calling it directly by its name, taking advantage of the fact that the `Player` class is a subclass of the `House` class. For this, first you have to initialize the superclass House inside the Player class:

```
class Player(House):
    def __init__(self):
        House.__init__(self)
```

With this you can call the `mailbox()` method of the parent class `House` directly with `self.mailbox()`. However, this won't work at this moment because you have a clash of namespaces inside the `House` class. You are assigning to the methods the same names as to the attributes of the class, so if you try to invoke `self.mailbox()` inside the Player class, the interpreter will understand that you're trying to invoke a string property as a method and throw the following error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. I recommend that you rename the methods like this:

```
def doorMethod(self):
    print("There is nothjing special about this door")

def vindovMethod(self):
    print("The vindov seems to be half open")

def mailboxMethod(self):
    print("there is an old mailbox")
```

Now you can invoke the mailboxMethod() inside the Player class. For this, instead of using a `while` loop, I recommend that you pack this call inside another function, like this:

```
def mailboxQ(self):
    action = input("> ")
    if action == "mailbox":
        self.mailbox()
```

Now in order to prompt the question inmediately to the user, you should call the method in the `__init__()` method of the Player `class`, right after the initialization of the parent `class` House.

I should also say that you probably don't want to try to initialize an instance of the House `class` inside itself, since this will lead you to a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`. You make a call to an object which hasn't yet been defined ;), so remove the following line from your code:

```
self.house = House()
```

These changes should leave your code now fully functional.

Comment: I always get te error self is not defined? what should i do